# Word for eighteen expressed as Twenty Minus Two

Tags: list-of-languages, numbers, numerals

Other than Latin, are there any languages that have a word for the number 18 that means twenty minus two?

A quick glance at some of the numeral systems of languages in the Indo-European reveal that 20 - 1 is common and there are some 30 - 1 words.

But I only know of 20 - 2 in Latin (duodeviginti).

Comment: Chan's list should be treated as just a sample, and not an extensive list of number-words, probably for any language. Hindi, for example, goes way beyond 30-1, but those numbers are not listed there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [a paper](http://www.linguistik-online.de/43_10/fabunmi.pdf) that gives an overview of the additive, subtractive and multiplicative derivations of number-words as used in the three dialects of Yoruba.

I'll quote a few things here, but the number system is far too complicated, and needs the paper I linked to to describe it.

> In the first pattern, it uses addition solely to derive the number words but with a counting pattern where 'ten', 'twenty' and the added number units are taken as a whole. In the second counting pattern, subtraction is used to derive number words but this is applicable only to three numbers i. e. seventeen – /mɛ́ɛtadínóɡu/, eighteen – /méèʤìdínóɡu/ and nineteen – /mɔkɔdínóɡ́u/.

In addition

> Most importantly, the idea expressed in [Standard Yoruba] and [Yoruba Ifè Nigeria] ... is 1 + 10, 2 + 10, 3 + 10, 4 + 10 for eleven to fourteen; and 20 - 5, 20 - 4, 20 - 3, 20 - 2, 20 - 1 for fifteen to nineteen; twenty (ogún) is a 
>   basic word.

The paper also compares the preferences of the older and newer generations of people when it comes to specific numbers.

Comment: thanks for that, prash! subtractives from 20 to 15 and 30, 40 etc certainly covers my question. it would be interesting to see a Togo/Yoruba abacus.

Answer (score 6):

The Salishan languages [**Bella Coola (Nuxálk)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nux%C3%A1lk_language) [[Denzer-King, pre-publication](http://rci.rutgers.edu/~rdenzerk/Numeral%20Convergence%20in%20the%20Plateau%20Linguistic%20Area.pdf)[PDF] and [2009](http://rci.rutgers.edu/~rdenzerk/A%20Preliminary%20Look%20at%20Restricted%20Counting%20in%20Proto-Salish.pdf)[PDF]] has "subtractive counting" for 3, 8 and 9:

`1 smaw`
`2 ɬnus`
`3 ʔa-smús`  ‘being next to + 4’
`4 smús`
`...`
`8 kʼi-ɬnus`  ‘lacking or without 2’
`9 kʼi-smaw`   ‘lacking or without 1’
`10 cʼklakt`

Some sources give **18** as [not subtractive](http://www.firstvoices.com/en/Nuxalk/word-category/20c51d4e52e47c52/NUMBERS), but [others have **18** as subtractive](http://lingweb.eva.mpg.de/numeral/):
`18 smawlakt-nus` ‘11+7’
`18 cʼklakt puƛʼs ʔa kʼiɬnus` ‘10+lacking 2’

Answer (score 3):

Ainu is one of those: (http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/ts/language/number/ainu.html)

```
1   sinep        1 obj.
2   tup          2 obj.
3   rep          3 obj.
4   inep         4 obj.
5   asiknep      5 obj.
6   iwanpe       6 obj.
7   arwanpe      7 obj.
8   tupesanpe    2 obj. to 10* obj.
9   sinepesanpe  1 obj. to 10* obj.
10  wanpe        10 obj.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any off the top of my head, but Eugene S. L. Chan has a large number of languages for which he has collected basic numeral terms:

http://lingweb.eva.mpg.de/numeral/

Comment: Yes, that's where I started to look, but then thought it might be quicker to ask here.

Comment: Janko Gorenc collects numbers but only up to ten IIRC.

Comment: Sigh, the link has gone stale. Is the resource available fron another place?